# Microsoft Connect died and breaks lots of links

Tags: discussion, broken-link

I don’t encounter this every day, but Stack Overflow and Exchange sites have a lot of links to [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/). For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12813535):

> **EDIT** This bug is now fixed: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766845/vs2012-the-compiler-generated-incorrect-codes-for-anonymous-methods

These now all redirect to an [irrelevant docs.microsoft.com page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect) because Microsoft isn’t hosting an archival read-only copy of Connect. Should something be done about this?

Comment: At least that solves the numerous times that connect site turned out to be a black hole.

Comment: If it was a bug that was fixed... just delete it.

Comment: @Braiam that is a fix for this instance. What about the [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aconnect.microsoft.com)?

Comment: @rene "Unfortunately, when you use a string, it will generate a false warning -- already reported to Microsoft (fixed in VS2010). Also the Code Analysis will complain about it (CA2243) -- reported to Microsoft (not fixed in VS2013)." Delete the reference. The answer will be the same. If it was a bug, and it was fixed, delete it.

Comment: @Braiam But I value being able to see the past discussion in the connect bugs. Also, there are many unfixed bugs with responses from MS on the Connect bug (which have slightly more authority than a quote from a random SO user who may be quoting something out of context or accidentally changing meaning), workarounds, links to fixes, etc.

Comment: This death was not instantaneous, Connect has been purged before and broke lots of links before.  The way-back machine doesn't capture these pages either, so it is just gone forever.  Otherwise the basic reason why a link should not be the meat of an answer.  "This bug is now fixed" is in fact good enough for old answers.

Comment: @binki "But I value being able to see the past discussion in the connect bugs" the history is there for anyone that is interested like you to see. People that are looking for answers to their questions should have to read paragraphs of unrelated outdated information.

Comment: Guh. If they can't keep the content up (surely they can afford it) they could at least not make it all "Permanently Moved" to a splash page. :( Is it just me or is this textbook poor webmastering?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Textbook poor webmastering" is a fair insult to lob at a lot of Microsoft's documentation. Broken links are common, the old MSDN docs links like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx were ugly and confusing, and the "**Note:**" at the top of the (still Google-topping) obsolete MSDN results for searching for any .NET API name just redirects to the .NET API browser splash page, from which actually hunting down the latest version of the docs you were reading is often difficult. This stuff confused me greatly when I started on a Windows stack.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I didn't say I was surprised ;) + :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yet, somehow still better than a lot of apple docs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It could be a strategy to force people to migrate to the newer, maintained and well-supported successor solutions.

Comment: @DBedrenko: Making migration almost impossible seems like a strange way to encourage migration.

Comment: @Yakk: I wouldn't know

Comment: Microsoft is actually quite good at writing documentation (ignoring MSDN samples). They are infuriatingly terrible at actually keeping stuff where people can find it, though. They reinvent their sites every few years, and seem to take particular glee in doing it in such a way to break as many links as possible. That's completely separate from the issue that they make documentation of stuff that's barely out of support vanish without a trace, which at least has the appalling if imaginable excuse of "we're forcing you to upgrade". Here endeth the rant.

Comment: There's probably no way of fixing all the links automatically. They migrated some of the stuff elsewhere, albeit clumsily -- a bug report I filed in Connect for SQL Server is now [in this subsection](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/), minus its details -- along with all the others that have been submitted, I suppose. I see no relation between the old link and the new, probably because there is none. Unless you already knew what was on the Connect page, you probably can't search for it elsewhere.

Comment: I've made a habit of including the title of any Microsoft link I use, so there's a prayer of finding it when (not if) Microsoft breaks the link. Bummer if there's no replacement link in this instance.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to have SE run a script to remove the protocol, thus making the link unclickable, and append ` (Dead Link)` after the link text . The example, inline-style answer would look like *"It is confirmed as a bug and now fixed: connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766845/vs2012-the-compiler-generated-incorrect-codes-for-anonymous-methods (Dead Link)"*, whilst a reference-style link would look like *"See here (Dead Link)."*. Maybe even have the script convert reference-style links to inline-style as sometimes the link itself contains useful info. cc@rene

Answer (score 13):

If we are looking for solutions to this:

- Trawling for all of the broken links caused by this could be automated.  Fixing them is a problem because it would be a manual task, and it would need to be repeated each time that Microsoft broke the site.  Not tenable.
- If we wanted to get into Microsoft's face about it, replace the broken links with a link that provides an easy way for SO readers to submit a complaint email to Microsoft.  But they will just figure out a way to black-hole the complaints.  Bad idea.
- Banning any links to Microsoft Connect would prevent this, but it makes it difficult to discuss Microsoft bugs.  The cure is worse than the disease.

In short.  No good solutions, unless Microsoft fix this.

Comment: Link only answers should be flagged as link only answer, and an answer should have the actual solution in the body so it's a self contained complete package. If that isn't the case the answer should be flagged as low quality.

Comment: 1.  No.  It is not a link only answer.  The actual answer is the three words:  "It is fixed".  The link is just supporting evidence.  2.  That particular answer is just an example.  I think the (Meta-) Question is about all of the Answers that have broken links.  Certainly that's what my (Meta- ) Answer is about!

Comment: Surely `connect.microsoft.com` is on the web archive, so couldn't we automate adding the `web.archive.org/whatever` prefix onto all `connect.microsoft.com` urls?

Comment: Nope, it isn't. A lot of the links don't work or load. isn't cached by google either.

Comment: @CalvT븃 That seems to not work even for the example in the question. http://web.archive.org/web/2/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766845/vs2012-the-compiler-generated-incorrect-codes-for-anonymous-methods

Comment: "Fixing them is a problem because it would be a manual task, and it would need to be repeated each time that Microsoft broke the site." It's not so bad. Inserting the links in the first place was also a manual task and I hope at least they won't brake their links every day. So manual fixing where beneficial (high traffic questions) may indeed be the way.

Comment: Except that the person doing the editing needs deep domain knowledge (and in many cases luck) to be able to identify the correct bug to link to.

Answer (score 0):

So, here goes a proactive idea - that may not be enough to fix what is already broken, but maybe can prevent future disasters in similar situation:

For each external link from Stack Exchange sites, Stack Exchange could fetch at least the structure and text on the target page and back it up internally. Later on a mechanism could be added so that upon verifying that the intended linked content is no longer in place, Stack Exchange users could perform an action on the post itself so that from then on the link will have beside it a small icon to see the fetched version, besides the original URL.

For text and code this should be a reasonable load to handle (if big), and if the target content is only available by running front-end code on the target link, that is a separate problem to be tackled later.

I started writing this with the intent to suggest triggering a fetch on the URL to http://archive.org, instead of having Stack Exchange make the content copy themselves - but I changed my mind and suggested an internal backup first thinking on the tremendous load that would go to archive.org instead, even though it is "their job". But a partnership with archive.org so that Stack Exchange could at least partially sponsor this extra load would be even better. (They already have all the expertise in fetching and retrieving the content that matters most, dealing with copyright issues on the contents fetched, and whatever they get turns out to be publicly available, not restricted to a single private entity, as awesome as Stack Exchange is.)

Comment: I think this is a rabbit hole SO would rather "skip" over.

Comment: Great idea! Shame it won't work.

Comment: So store stuff just in case the link breaks? Sounds like a lot of wasted money to by extra storage.

Comment: Have you ever heard of "backups"? Also, are you aware of the space actually taken by text? (until you bloat it with metadata no one will actulally use at least)?
It is more like all human-readable-text in all external links on stack exchange even today would not fill a domestic PC's HD.  (Of course, not counting javascript code in the pages as human readable, as the requirements tree for even a short three-paragraph page can surpass easily several MB if using modern front-end libraries)

Comment: Sounds like archive.org to me. No need to reinvent the wheel. Just submit the external links from here to them and support them financially a bit.

Comment: @Trilarion: yes, that was my initial though on the thing. And reading in retrospect the number of wheels that would have to be re-invented (not so much technical, but also legal), it seems it would just be the right thing to do.